# Create index.php that executes different statements if user inputs different folder in url

Tags: php, if-statement, redirect, indexing

On my server i have everything redirected to index.php
I have to My index.php works as user inputs url

```
http://ip:80/index.php
then it executes php script as follows

'$input = trim($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "/")

if(){statement}else{statement}'

I want to edit that index file so it executes 2 different if statements 
For example if user inputs this url  http://ip:80/server1/index.php
then it executes statement 1

`if(){statement 1}
if(){statement 2}
else{statement}`

if user inputs url as http://ip:80/server2/index.php then it executes statement2

`if(){statement 1}
if(){statement 2}
else{statement}'
```

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need to **redirect** everything to your index.php.
On most Apache server, you can set the direction with a **.htaccess** file, like so :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Next, you simply have to check the `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` value, for example :

```
$input = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
if (strpos($input, 'server1/')!==false) {
      // statement 1
} else if (strpos($input, 'server2/')!==false) {
      // statement 2
} else {
      // default statement
}
```

I suggest you read about [URL rewriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php) for more information.